# ¿Cómo hago para sacar un dato específico de un txt?

Tags: python

Necesito extraer un dato específico:

```
("NumeroLinea":1:"Codigo":"2449099000200":"CodigoComercial":["Tipo":"99":"Codigo":"7441003584488"]:"Cantidad":1.000:)
```

de este archivo TURRUCARES":"Telefono":"CodigoPais":506:"NumTelefono":24879495:"Fax":null:"CorreoElectronico":"facturasdontony@gmail.com":"Receptor":null:"CondicionVenta":"01":"PlazoCredito":null:"MedioPago":["01":null:null:null]:"DetalleServicio":"LineaDetalle":["NumeroLinea":1:"Codigo":"2449099000200":"CodigoComercial":["Tipo":"99":"Codigo":"7441003584488"]:"Cantidad":1.000:"UnidadMedida":"Unid":"UnidadMedidaComercial":"Otros":"Detalle":"POWERADE AVALANCHA ALPINA

Este es el código que tengo:

```py
with open("D:\Documents\Archivo xml\data10000.txt","r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        print(linea)
    contenido = archivo.read()
    guardado = contenido.split("NumeroLinea:1:Codigo:2449099000200:CodigoComercial:[Tipo:99:Codigo:7441003584488]:Cantidad:1.000:")
    final_file = open("new_file.txt" , "w")
    final_file.write(linea)
    final_file.close()
```

Pero no lo imprime.

Comment: podrías colocar la forma en la que tienes tu archivo txt por favor

Comment: te referis a esto D:\Documents\Archivo xml\data10000.txt

Comment: ¿qué dato especifico quieres sacar? ¿qué esperas que haga esto `contenido.split("NumeroLinea:1:Codigo:2449099000200:CodigoComercial:[Tipo:99:Codigo:7441003584488]:Cantidad:1.000:")`?

Comment: @BrunoTorres si... pero el contenido de eso

Comment: TURRUCARES":"Telefono":"CodigoPais":506:"NumTelefono":24879495:"Fax":null:"CorreoElectronico":"facturasdontony@gmail.com":"Receptor":null:"CondicionVenta":"01":"PlazoCredito":null:"MedioPago":["01":null:null:null]:"DetalleServicio":"LineaDetalle":["NumeroLinea":1:"Codigo":"2449099000200":"CodigoComercial":["Tipo":"99":"Codigo":"7441003584488"]:"Cantidad":1.000:"UnidadMedida":"Unid":"UnidadMedidaComercial":"Otros":"Detalle":"POWERADE AVALANCHA ALPINA

Comment: Agregarlo a la pregunta,aquí no se ve bien

Comment: No creo que hayas estructirado bien tu archivo txt